# Predict_proba array with the most relevant predictions

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, scikit-learn, prediction

I'm doing multi label classification in Python (using sklearn library) and wondering how can I receive the top 5 classes for each predicted label from predict_proba() function in the array form looking just like that:

```
y_pred=[[1,3,4,5,2],[4,3,2,1,5],[1,2,3,5,4]]
```

How can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to reproduce the code you have. Here is a solution based on some assumption.

If you can store the

> predict_proba()

as a series using,

> pd.Series(fit.predict_proba(testdata)[0])

you can probably use

> predict_proba(testdata).nlargest(n=5)

to determine the top 5 probabilities with the index, sorted automatically